# I cannot find fritzing 2x3 pin header

Tags: arduino

How can I get an 2x3 pin header (used for ISP programming for atmega, for example), to appear in Fritzing? I cannot find it in the parts list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please correct me, if I'm wrong, but I think the 2x3 pin header is still in the fritzing [standard library](https://github.com/fritzing/fritzing-parts/tree/master/core). I searched in the part toolbar "2x3" and find the header with the following description:

> AVR ISP 6 Pin This is the reduced ISP connector for AVR programming.
>   Common on Arduino. This footprint will take up less PCB space and can
>   be used with a 10-pin to 6-pin adapter such as SKU: BOB-08508